# Javascript get output from separate php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want javascript to be able to call a php script (which just echos a string) using jQuery.

I think `$.get` is the right way, but not too sure.

I then want to use the returned string as a javascript variable.

Comment: You are looking for Ajax; `$.get()` and the other Ajax functions in jQuery are indeed the right way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$.get() is the way to go, indeed.

First of all, you will need a page / url that outputs the result of the function you want to use (for example, *www.yoursite.com/test_output.php* ). You should create that page and call the function you want to use there.
Also keep in mind that I said **output**, not return, because .get will fetch the output of the http response, not the returned value of the php function.

So if you have the following function defined in your site (you can also define it in test_output.php, of course):

```
<?php 
function say_hello() {
 return 'hello world';
}
?>
```

In test_output.php, you will need something like this:

```
<?php
echo say_hello();
?>
```

Then on the client side, you need some JavaScript / jQuery:

```
var data_from_ajax;

$.get('http://www.yoursite.com/test_output.php', function(data) {
  data_from_ajax = data;
});
```

Now you have the output of the ajax .get() function stored in data_from_ajax and you can use it as you please.

Answer (score 7):

[$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is the right way.

```
$.get('ajax/test.php', function(data) {
  // use the result
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm using which works fine on it's own, but trying to build in with a function and it's not.

Comment: Working, just a misplaced bracket