# include result of php file javascript

Tags: php, javascript, web

[solved]

I am trying to build an image gallery from scratch.
I have a directory of php files that are each the thumbnail for an album. Each with this structure:

```
<div class="pic">   
    <img id="albcov" onclick="showAlbum(this)"  src="someimg.jpg"
    Alt="albumtitle"
</div>
```

The relevant js:

```
 function showAlbum(img){   
     var albumname=img.alt   
     document.getElementById("albcont").innerHTML = [executed contents of: albumname     serverside php file];  
 }
```

How could I fetch the required file?

This php file will generate a list of thumbnails for the specified album.
Which in turn will all the full images to be shown.

as I understand it it will require ajax of some sort.

**edit: here is the code i am using now:**

```
function showAlbum(img){
    albumName = img.alt;
    $('#albcont').load("/gallery/"+albumName+".php");
}
```

where albumname.php contains:

```
<p>
<?php foreach (glob("[albumname]/*.php") as $filename)

{
    include ($filename);
}
?>
</p>
```

which includes all php files in that album which have structure:

```
<div class="galpic">
<img onmouseover="displayImage(this)" src="
someimg.jpg
"  alt="
alt
" />
<p>
caption
</p>
</div>
```

and the JS for this is:

```
function displayImage(img) {
    var imgname= img.src
    var albumname= img.alt
    document.getElementById("imgview").innerHTML ='<img src="'+imgname+'"/>';

}
```

example to view at [lonjaselter.co.nr/gallery2.php](http://lonjaselter.co.nr/gallery2.php)

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727446/javascript-get-output-from-separate-php-script

Comment: When you say ' I have a directory of php files that are each...' do you mean the  above structure EG has its php file? If so would it not be easier to have these contained in one php so you only require to load one file rather that several. Yes, Ajax will be required if you want to load them in via js. Look up jQuery Ajax this will give you an insight.

Comment: "as I understand it it will require ajax of some sort". It will; do you have any experience with ajax? Are you already using some kind of ajax library or framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using ajax. By jQuery you can accomplish it so easily to for more you can [jQuery AJAX Api Doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

By Using jQuery Ajax request code is

```
/*i assume that img is id of the element that you are passing as parameter. in jQuery Way*/ 
function showAlbum(img){
   var imgId = '#'+ img, 
       albumName = $(imgId).attr('alt'); 
   $('#albcont').load("http://yourdomainname/path/to/"+albumname+".php");
}
```