# How to get the whole contents of the file containing a javascript function into a string in the javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file

For instance, say I have the HTML page `index.html`. It has a javascript function `someFn()` (upon `onclick`) that needs to obtain the entire contents of this page (which also has text fields that are modified by the user. (So as a result, the page contents will be modified from the original content.) Eventually, this `someFn()` will try to obtain the entire contents of the page in a variable. This variable is then passed on to a PHP script in another file that does the required work. Alternatively, it may output it to a file which is read by the aforementioned PHP script.

The only problem is how the JS function will obtain the page contents in a variable. jQuery alternatives are welcome as long as they don't mess with the workflow of data shown above.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? We can help better if we understand the actual useage

Comment: `var page = $('html').html()` page will contain the content of the whole page.

Comment: Try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727446/javascript-get-output-from-separate-php-script

Answer (score 3):

Try using `XMLSerializer.serializeToString()` [Get DocType of an HTML as string with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript)  to retrieve `document.doctype` as string , `document.documentElement.outerHTML` to retrieve `html` of root element of `document`

```
   var html =  new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.doctype) 
               + document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```